# Query not working - MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

Given this kind of documents:

```
 "_id" : ObjectId("5461c8f0426f727f16010000"),
    "f" : [ 
        {
            "t" : "ry",
            "v" : 1972
        }, 
        {
            "t" : "g",
            "v" : [ 
                "Crime", 
                "Drama"
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "t" : "ml",
            "v" : "English"
        }, 
        {
            "t" : "k",
            "v" : "movie"
        }, 
        {
            "t" : "ai",
            "v" : 972353
        }, 
        {
            "t" : "ec",
            "v" : 46
        }, 
        {
            "t" : "rel",
            "v" : true
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to query for those which "ry" is greater than 1980 and which "g" (genre) is "Drama" or "Thriller".

I made up this query:

```
db.items.find( 
    {
        "$or": [
            {"f": $elemMatch: {"t": "ry", "v": {$gt: 1980}}},
            {"f": $elemMatch: {"t": "g", "v": {$in: ["Drama"]}}}
        ]
    }

)
```

But it is not working:

`Error: Line 4: Unexpected token :`

Any idea why is this?

Comment: you missed `{` after `$elemMatch` `{"f":{"$elemMatch": {"t":....`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you've missed some brackets before $elemMatch:

```
db.items.find( 
    {
        "$or": [
            {"f": {$elemMatch: {"t": "ry", "v": {$gt: 1980}}}},
            {"f": {$elemMatch: {"t": "g", "v": {$in: ["Drama"]}}}}
        ]
    }

)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing curly braces around $elemMatch.